# How to interpret the Ambari Metrics graph 'Network Usage'?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm running a small Ambari cluster of 3 masters and 3 workers. This cluster is connected to an Oracle database that's not part of the cluster. 
Ambari metrics in Ambari manager shows a 'Network Usage' widget, with an 'in' and 'out' line. My question is: how do I interpret this traffic?
Does data from/to the Oracle database (outside the cluster) get incorporated in network usage? Or does it only reflect traffic going between the nodes? What exactly does 'in' and 'out' stand for in this context?

Answer (score 0):

For me its not totally clear but From HWKs documention, I could find this answer:

"Network usage The cluster-wide network utilization, including in-and-out"

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.6.2.0/bk_ambari-operations/bk_ambari-operations.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjr9oeFse3fAhUK1RoKHV7XDo0QFjAAegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw2sVnPGQ7wKPBHi_T8nyri9